# Computing $\mathbb E [Z_1 \mid Z_1 > Z_2]$ for $Z_1, Z_2$ iid gaussians

Tags: probability, expected-value, conditional-expectation

I'm having trouble computing the expectation:

$$\mathbb E [Z_1 \mid Z_1 > Z_2]$$

even in the simple case where $Z_1, Z_2$ are iid standard normal rvs. It's clear to me that, at least in some cases, conditioning on the event $Z_1>Z_2$ does give us some information about $Z_1$: consider the case where $Z_2$ is a constant.

My typical approach for this kind of problem would be to condition on $Z_2$ and try take advantage of the independence assumption:

$$\mathbb E [Z_1 \mid Z_1 > Z_2] =\mathbb E \left [\mathbb E [Z_1 \mid Z_1 > Z_2, Z_2] \mid Z_1 > Z_2\right ]$$

But that does not help much since I cannot simplify the inner expectation.

At first glance I would guess the expectation should be easy to compute, but I am having trouble simplifying it using properties of expectation (or by trying to compute a marginal distribution which I can use to express the expectation). How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(\mu,\sigma)=\mathbb E(Z_1\mid Z_1>Z_2)$ when the $Z$'s are $\mathcal N(\mu,\sigma^2)$'s. It is intuitively clear that $f(\mu,\sigma^2)=\sigma f(0,1)+\mu$, so we only need to calculate $f(0,1)$.

It is also intuitively clear that $\mathbb P(Z_1>Z_2)=\frac12$, so the pdf of $Z_1$ given $Z_1>Z_2$ is
$$f_{Z_1\mid Z_1>Z_2}(x)=\left(\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^xe^{-(x^2+y^2)/2}\,dy\right)\bigg/\frac12$$
$$=\frac1\pi\int_{-\infty}^xe^{-(x^2+y^2)/2}\,dy$$
Thus
$$f(0,1)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac x\pi\int_{-\infty}^xe^{-(x^2+y^2)/2}\,dy\,dx$$
$$=\frac1\pi\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-y^2/2}\int_y^\infty xe^{-x^2/2}\,dx\,dy$$
$$=\frac1\pi\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-y^2/2}\int_{y^2/2}^\infty e^{-u}\,du\,dy$$
$$=\frac1\pi\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-y^2}\,dy=\frac1{\sqrt\pi}$$
and $f(\mu,\sigma)=\frac\sigma{\sqrt\pi}+\mu$.

Comment: Good point, it's actually easy to find the pdf in this case.

Comment: @Parcly Taxel The step where you wrote down the conditional density was too fast for me, so I recalculated it and obtained $f_{Z_1\mid Z_1>Z_2}(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^xe^{-(x^2+y^2)/2}\,dy$, so it differs from your answer by a factor of $2$ (as well as the final result). Can you please recheck? If you are sure of your calculation, I will add mine so we can compare.

Comment: @iljusch I integrated the conditional pdf alone when I wrote it down as a check and it came out to $1$ as expected.

Comment: @Parcly Taxel Oh, right! I made a mistake. Now things add up. Thanks for the clarification.